# Order Infinite Matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_{m,j}\}_{m,j \in \Bbb N} \in \Bbb C$ such that for each $m$ the sequence $a_{m,j} \in c_{00}$ definitely zero sequence and for each $j$ we have $\lim_{m \to \infty}a_{m,j}=0$

Let $\{j_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \in \Bbb N$ a sequence of $\Bbb N$

I would like to know if $$\sup(|a_{m,j_m}|)_{m \in\Bbb N}<\infty$$ 
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "definitely zero sequence"?  Would a counterexample be $a_{n,n} = n$, $a_{n,j} = 0$ otherwise?

Comment: The answer is no.  You would need to have some kind of "uniform convergence" among the rows and/or columns

Comment: @RobertIsrael exist $k$ such that $a_{m,j}=0$ for each $j>k$

Comment: @RobertIsrael a sequence with at most finitely many non-zero elements.  So yes it would.

Comment: thanks @Omnomnomnom , can you tell me what kind of uniform convergence

Comment: @MateyMath we'd need to be able to say something like: "for all $\epsilon > 0$: there exists an $m_0$ such that **for all j**: $m < m_0 \implies |a_{m,j}| < \epsilon$"

Comment: ok @Omnomnomnom thanks for this